# Why Java HashMap put is not working in Spark Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a sample Spark dataframe as follows:

```
val mydf1 = Seq((1, "a"), (2, "b"),(3, "c"),(4, "d"),(5, "e")).toDF("id", "col2")

scala> mydf1.show
+---+----+
| id|col2|
+---+----+
|  1|   a|
|  2|   b|
|  3|   c|
|  4|   d|
|  5|   e|
+---+----+
```

I am trying to add the above dataframe to a Java util HashMap as follows:

```
import java.util._
val jmap = new java.util.HashMap[Integer, String]()

mydf1.rdd.foreach{case Row(id: Integer, col2: String) => jmap.put(id, col2)}
```

But after the above code I still don't see the ids and col2s getting added to the jmap HashMap as below:

```
scala> jmap.size
res13: Int = 0
```

Am I missing something in my implementation?

I know I could use Scala converters, but for some reason I don't want to use it.

Comment: You realize that the executors are filling the copy of the jmap that was sent to each of them in the closure, not the jmap that you defined in your driver? There is no way to update driver variables from an executor.

Comment: My end goal is to create a Java HashMap and write it to disk. Can't I achieve it in anyway?

Comment: I think you asked a similar question earlier, and I believe it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The question is why you think the correct solution for writing on disk is to serialize a Java HashMap. What is the problem you are actually trying to solve?

Comment: Spark already provides a lot of method for writing an `RDD \ DF \ DS` to a **Distributed File System** _(like HDFS or S3)_ in multiple formats _(like CSV, JSON, Parquet, ORC)_. Since Spark is intended for **"BigData"**, it does not make sense _(from a conceptual point of view)_ to write to a local disk, because your data is supposed to be big enough to do not fill in one machine - now, if you are sure your data will fill in one machine, you may collect the DF first and then save the local scala collection. But once again, you may consider it you are really using Spark for what it is intended.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I need to load the Scala HashMap as a Java HashMap in a different environment. In one environment, I have Scala, and on the other environment I have Java. Exporting the dataframe to a csv file and reading it back on the other environment is taking a lot time as the CSV file size becomes 104MB. So I though exporting the object itself and reading the object again would reduce this loading time.

Comment: If the other environment also uses the same spark cluster and the same filesystem (e.g. HDFS) you may want to just save it as parquet and read it as a dataset in the Java program. Or you may serialize each object individually (a stream of pairs). Also check why CSV is slowing you down. Is it parsing time? Do you read the entire CSV to memory?

Comment: @RealSkeptic The other environment does not have any Spark cluster setup. It is purely just a Java environment. The idea is to do all the heavy analysis tasks in the Spark cluster and export this lookup table from the Spark cluster to a file which I can load back in the Java environment for lookups. Also, I am doing FileStreamReading the CSV row by row and populating a Java HashMap. Is this slowing me down?

Comment: @user3243499 what about writing your output to a database? - or will the latency in the queries be too slow? and thus you really need a map? - in such case what about a more lightweight format like protobuf? - Anyways, if the Java environment is a server, I don't think a slowdown on the start is too bad, or is the environment resetting constantly?

Comment: If you have your own custom CSV reading mechanism, you should consider using a good library for that instead. You may benefit from proper buffering and escaping.

Answer (score 0):

RDD is a distributed collection spread over in different executors in the cluster and ***foreach*** being executed in executor nodes. Whereas ***jmap*** is a local collection object, though its being sent over to individual executors (since its being invoked within ***foreach***), but it will not come back to the driver with added values.

One way is to do is that, collect all rdd values in the driver and add them into ***jmap*** (But this is not advisable for large collection though)

```
mydf1.rdd.collect().foreach{case Row(id: Integer, col2: String) => jmap.put(id, col2)}
```